# No "Edit sample values" icon in Blend 4

Tags: blend, sample-data, expression-blend-4

I have a random problem that I can't seem to fix.  I don't see the "**Edit sample values**" icon in my sample data in Blend.  It's normally there, but for this project it's not.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if there's a setting or fix?

I can of course still edit the data in the XAML, but it's nice to use that interface.

Fine Details:

- XAML based sample data source
- Created through the interface in Blend
- Tried recreating the data source
- Happens on two different data sources
- One is bound to a view, the other is not

Thanks in advance!